# I used GROUPBY then SUMMARISE to add a total label to dataframe. BUT means the % data on total level is wrong

Tags: r, loops, group-by, summarize

I used GROUPBY then SUM then SUMMARISE to add a total label to dataframe.  BUT means the % data on total level is wrong.   So, I would like to overwrite the percentage variable 'percentage absent staff' with a calculation with the correct result.  Problem is that it is a long data set, impossible to do manually.  Looking for good solution, LOOP or something else maybe?

[image]

Code:

```
Date=c("01/09/2020","01/09/2020","01/09/2020","01/09/2020",
       "01/09/2020","01/09/2020","01/09/2020","01/09/2020",
       "02/09/2020","02/09/2020","02/09/2020","02/09/2020",
       "02/09/2020","02/09/2020","02/09/2020","02/09/2020")

Asset=c("Blue Hotel","Blue Hotel","Blue Hotel","Blue Hotel",
        "Green Hotel","Green Hotel","Green Hotel","Green Hotel",
        "Blue Hotel","Blue Hotel","Blue Hotel","Blue Hotel",
        "Green Hotel","Green Hotel","Green Hotel","Green Hotel")

Variable=c("hotel staff","bar staff","absent staff","percentage absent 
   staff",
           "hotel staff","bar staff","absent staff","percentage absent staff",
           "hotel staff","bar staff","absent staff","percentage absent staff",
           "hotel staff","bar staff","absent staff","percentage absent staff")
value=c(5,10,3,0.2,4,8,2,0.17,5,10,3,0.20,6,3,3,0.33)

df=data.frame(Date,Asset,Variable,value)

#to create totals
df2= df %>% 
  group_by(Date,Variable) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(as.numeric(value), na.rm=F)) %>% ungroup()
```

Comment: How about a reproducible example?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I added this....

Comment: If you can provide your code and make the dataframe in the code will be easier. No one wants to type everything in the image to answer the question. People can help you based on your code.

Comment: Sorry, done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what calculation you want because one the first "correct" calculation looks like absent_staff/(hotel_staff + bar_staff + absent_staff) and the second correct calculation looks like absent_staff/(hotel_staff + bar_staff).  However, you can craft the solution below to your liking.

```
df2= df %>% 
  group_by(Date,Variable) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(as.numeric(value), na.rm=F)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(value = case_when(
           Variable == "percentage absent staff" ~ value[which(Variable == "absent staff")]/
                    sum(value[which(Variable %in% c("absent staff", "bar staff", "hotel staff"))]), 
           TRUE ~ value)
         )
df2
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# # Groups:   Date [2]
#     Date       Variable                 value
#     <chr>      <chr>                    <dbl>
# 1 01/09/2020 absent staff             5    
# 2 01/09/2020 bar staff               18    
# 3 01/09/2020 hotel staff              9    
# 4 01/09/2020 percentage absent staff  0.156
# 5 02/09/2020 absent staff             6    
# 6 02/09/2020 bar staff               13    
# 7 02/09/2020 hotel staff             11    
# 8 02/09/2020 percentage absent staff  0.2
```

In the above, you group the summarised data by `Date` and then replace value with a conditional expression.  When `Variable` is equal to `"percentage absent staff"` the value will be the value for `"absent staff"` divided by the sum of the values for `"absent staff", "bar staff", "hotel staff"`.  So, if you really wanted the second calculation from above, you could just leave `"absent staff"` out of this vector. Otherwise, `value` will be returned as the same value it was originally.

---

**EDIT**

To answer questions in the comment, if there are other resident values in the same variable - `Variable` with the same structure, you could reqplce those with:

```
Date=c("01/09/2020","01/09/2020","01/09/2020","01/09/2020",
       "01/09/2020","01/09/2020","01/09/2020","01/09/2020",
       "02/09/2020","02/09/2020","02/09/2020","02/09/2020",
       "02/09/2020","02/09/2020","02/09/2020","02/09/2020")

Asset=c("Blue Hotel","Blue Hotel","Blue Hotel","Blue Hotel",
        "Green Hotel","Green Hotel","Green Hotel","Green Hotel",
        "Blue Hotel","Blue Hotel","Blue Hotel","Blue Hotel",
        "Green Hotel","Green Hotel","Green Hotel","Green Hotel")

Variable=c("hotel staff","bar staff","absent staff","percentage absent staff",
           "hotel staff","bar staff","absent staff","percentage absent staff",
           "hotel staff","bar staff","absent staff","percentage absent staff",
           "hotel staff","bar staff","absent staff","percentage absent staff")
value=c(5,10,3,0.2,4,8,2,0.17,5,10,3,0.20,6,3,3,0.33)

df=data.frame(Date,Asset,Variable,value)

#to create totals

dfr <- df
dfr$Variable <- gsub("staff", "residents", dfr$Variable)
dfr$value <- rpois(nrow(dfr), 25)
df <- bind_rows(df, dfr)
df[c(1:5, 17:21), ]


df2= df %>% 
  group_by(Date,Variable) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(as.numeric(value), na.rm=F)) %>% ungroup()



df2a= df2 %>% 
  group_by(Date,Variable) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(as.numeric(value), na.rm=F)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(value = case_when( Variable == "percentage absent staff" ~ value[which(Variable == "absent staff")]/ 
                              sum(value[which(Variable %in% c("absent staff", "bar staff", "hotel staff"))]),
                            Variable == "percentage absent residents" ~ value[which(Variable == "absent residents")]/ 
                              sum(value[which(Variable %in% c("absent residents", "bar residents", "hotel residents"))]),
                            TRUE ~ value) )
```

Comment: Great, this works.  Is there a way to nest an additional calculation in?  In reality I have a large df with many calculations.  I tried adding the next one below but doesn't work? In the example below I try to add residents calc under the staff calc...

Comment: Code I tried is:

group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(value = case_when(
           Variable == "percentage absent staff" ~ value[which(Variable == "absent staff")]/
                    sum(value[which(Variable %in% c("absent staff", "bar staff", "hotel staff"))]), 
           TRUE ~ value)mutate(value = case_when(
           Variable == "percentage absent residents" ~ value[which(Variable == "absent residents")]/sum(value[which(Variable %in% c("absent residents", "bar residents", "hotel residents"))]), 
           TRUE ~ value)

Comment: Yes, the code worked - I just want to add (nest) a second calculation in so tried to add another but issue with my syntax.  Tried to post it but too many characters it seems...

Comment: Perhaps post a new question or edit your existing question to add this piece.

Comment: 1 of 4: @DaveArmstrong.  Basically, the code that works is as you suggested:  
df2= df %>% 
  group_by(Date,Variable) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(as.numeric(value), na.rm=F)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(value = case_when(
           Variable == "percentage absent staff" ~ value[which(Variable == "absent staff")]/
                    sum(value[which(Variable %in% c("absent staff", "bar staff", "hotel staff"))]), 
           TRUE ~ value)
         )

Comment: 2 of 4:  I want to add an additional percentage calculation, in reality the dataset is much larger.  I want to replicate this part of the code: 
 group_by(Date) %>% mutate(value = case_when( Variable == "percentage absent staff" ~ value[which(Variable == "absent staff")]/ sum(value[which(Variable %in% c("absent staff", "bar staff", "hotel staff"))]), TRUE ~ value) )

Comment: 3 of 4: but nest in the same piece of code as in 1 of 3: above.  The new calculation is;
mutate(value = case_when( Variable == "percentage absent residents" ~ value[which(Variable == "absent residents")]/sum(value[which(Variable %in% c("absent residents", "bar residents", "hotel residents"))]), TRUE ~ value)

Comment: 4 of 4:  but my syntax seems bad so the code doesn't work when I add in the second calculation.  Sorry, does that make it clearer, I know is confusing....

Comment: In your dataset, are the resident and staff identifiers in the same variable named `Variable` or are they in a different variable?

Comment: Hmmm, almost works - problem is the second calculation doesn't seem to take the sum of the denominator (c("absent residents", "bar residents", "hotel residents") for all hotels, yet the first one does?  I'll need to investigate further....

Comment: @4agreements Looks like I forgot a step, I edited the answer accordingly.  It should work now.

Comment: One thing though, when I compare to excel the calculation outcome is a little different, could it be rounded to different number of decimals?

Comment: Perhaps, the best thing to do would be to pick a few and do them out by hand to make sure that the one method you want to use is doing it right.